# HTML table - best format for storing user table style preferences

Tags: html, xml, json, html-table

I have a web page which feeds users data in HTML tabular format.  The table can be quite complex and long (say 40-50 columns in total).  Different users will be interested in different columns, so to accommodate, the user has the ability to modify the columns of the table to his own preferences, so that he can:

- change their width
- change their order
- set them hidden

(Each table has a unique table-id, and each column in a table has a unique Id within that table.)

The problem, of course, is that the next time the user uses the website, he won't want to spend time again re-configuring his preferences.  So my website needs to store his preferences (which I can do in his database profile).

But what is the best way of storing the required data, so that (using JavaScript) I can re-draw the table for the user, as he last left it?

I can use either XML or JSON as a technical platform for storing the required information.

But the question is, what is the best format for storing each column's width, position and visibility, in such a way that my JavaScript can redraw his screen with minimum processing?

The problem, really, is that sometimes I need to access the column's data by referencing the column ID, and other times by its numeric position.  So sometimes an object would be a better option, and sometimes an array.

Interested to know how other people store this kind of data.

**--EDIT--**

To re-word the question (and abstract away from the real world situation of HTML tables), I suppose what I really want to know is:

> **How do I best store data in such a way that I can access it by both
>   its ID (primary-key) and Numeric-Index, given that the Index of the ID
>   (primary-key) can change over time.**

Comment: i would try to define 2-5 widths as css classes and store the cell.className, the cell.style.display, and the cell.cellIndex as a col  object in an array of all cols.

Comment: @dandavis regarding the column width - I need to be more specific than that, and give the user more flexibility. Besides, I don't see how it is easier to store a class-name as opposed to a number which represents a pixel-width.

Comment: @dandavis: I agree, I could just store the properties in an array. But what to do when I need to access the column by its ID (rather than by its index).  It is an expensive overhead to have to search every entry in an array to find the column's ID.  This really, is the core of my question.  How do I store the data, so that I can access it both by its column position (i.e. an array), and by its ID (i.e. an Object, or associative array).

Comment: adding id to each object and calling my earlier array cols: byId={}; cols.forEach(function(a){this[a.id]=a;}, byId); then, byId["xyz"] will be instant and give you both modes of access with just one linear-time iteration at the start. since objects are passed by ref, changes to byId cells will affect cols cells. RE: #1, classes are going to be MUCH faster to render to a table than touching each col and causing an expensive table-layout recalc for each col.

Comment: @dandavis If you post your suggestion as an answer, rather than as a comment, there is a greater chance of it being accepted as the official answer.